# ImageMagick: convert multiple jpg to pdf "The file “myimages.pdf” could not be opened" error on a Mac

Tags: macos, terminal, imagemagick

I have this set of images: image1.jpg, image2.jpg, image3.jpg

I've tried this on my MacOS Sierra using ImageMagick 6.9.8-4:

```
convert *.jpg myimages.pdf
```

It runs without errors, but when I double click on the PDF, I get the following pop up message error:

```
The file “myimages.pdf” could not be opened.

It may be damaged or use 
a file format that Preview doesn’t recognize.
```

Comment: Have you tried it with other files, how many files are you converting, and how was ImageMagick installed?

Comment: ImageMagick was installed using Brew. I've tried converting a single image to PDF and it worked, but when I tried 4 other images it didn't work. All images are the same size. I have tried with different PNGs and the same problem.

Comment: The latest version of IM 7.0.5.5 has a bug in creating valid multipage PDF files. See http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=31870#p145739